# Commandline args has no value, yet code gives an output?

Tags: java

I run this as a Java application in Eclipse. Surprisingly, it prints the first line. I was expecting it to print the second. I never entered anything in the command line, so why does this happen?

```
class Game
{   
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if(args != null){
            System.out.println("Lets do something with args");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Cant do something until args is not null"); 
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT -**

Also tried another thing in response to one of the answers. Remove all code in main and substitute it with this -

```
System.out.println("Main method..."); 
for(int i = 0; i< args.length; i++){
System.out.println("i = " + i); 
}
```

output is main method. Why ?

Comment: The array itself is not null.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `null` and an empty array?  Keep in mind that arrays in java are objects (and so can be null or not null).

Comment: @T-Biscuit - page not found.

Comment: @SuperStar see my edited answer for your edited question

Answer (score 5):

The `args` array is empty, not `null`. You need to do this:

```
if (args.length > 0) {
    System.out.println("Lets do something with args");
} else {
    System.out.println("Cant do something until args is not empty");
}
```

Before your program is run something like the following happens:

```
args = new String[0]; // create a new, empty array of strings
```

After this each argument from the command line, if any, is added to this array. Then your main function is called with this args array as the parameter.

There is a difference between a null array and and empty array. First of all, an array isn't just a set of values. It needs a container that stores 2 main things: the actual values and a length variable (so that you don't have to count the values each time). This container (a Java class) needs storage too. It needs to be allocated.

If you do:

```
String[] args;
```

you just have an `args` variable of type `String[]`. It has never been assigned to so it has no storage. Java initializes it to `null`. Think of `null` as the number zero. It is just a convention, meaning that it's not initialized. You can't access anything in `args` (`args.length` for example) because the class args should be naming doesn't exist yet. If you try you'll get a NullPointerException.

If you do:

```
String[] args = new String[0];
```

you now have an `args` variable of type `String[]`, but it's also initialized with a new `String[]` class. This array class by default has no values and a length equal to zero. But this class exists. You can think of `args` as now being a number (address), different than zero (the `null` in the previous case), that identifies this class which is stored somewhere in memory. In effect, when you now do `args.length` you're telling Java to access the class that is identified by the address `args` contains (you normally can't see this address in the code, or anywhere, Java handles this for you), and from inside that class get the length variable. Similarly, when you do `args[0]` you first get the class from memory and then retrieve the first value from it.

Comment: If it is not null, then what is it ? What is it assigned to ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass any command line arguments to the program, `args` will not be `null` but rather a 0-length `String[]`. Try printing `args.length` - a `null` value would throw an exception whereas a 0-length array would print `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The `args` is not `null` but is empty.

It's not that it is called by `jvm` like this

```
               `Game.main(null);`
```

But similar to this:

```
        `Game.main(new String[0]);` //in the case of no args.
```

1. NULL:So if `String[] args=null`, you will get `NullPointerException` when you try to access like `args.length` etc. So, `args` is null here.
2. EMPTY ARRAY:But if `String[] args=new String[0]`, you won't run into such problems.

So, you can just see if the array has no elements in which case `args.length` is zero. So, `args` is empty here.

```
  `if(args.length>0)` is what you need.
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

> output is main method. Why ?

Because `args.length` is 0 in your case and `i=0`, `i<args.length`,`0<0` condition fails hence no iteration is made.

Answer (score 0):

The command line `args` is just empty `[]`, it is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The command line String array is not `null` it is just empty. It does not contain any elements.

For your edit, 
the output is `main method` because the loop will not iterate one time also.
This is because array has zero elements and hence it will not enter the loop a single time also.

Answer (score 0):

The array is empty, if you want to test with arguments in eclipse follow the steps below:

```
Right click the class -> Run as -> Run Configuration -> Arguments Tab
```

Add some text to the `Program Arguments` text area